# Combining these two expression into a single LINQ expression

Tags: c#, html, linq, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using the `HTMLAgilityPack` to parse through some html. I am getting the result set that I am expecting when using and `xpath` query combined with a linq query. Is there a way that I could combine them both into a single LINQ query?

```
var test = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='product']");

foreach (var item in test)
{

    var result = from input in item.Descendants("span")
                 where input.Attributes["class"].Value == "Bold"
                 where input.InnerHtml.ToUpper() == "GetItem"
                 select input;   

    return result;           
}
```

Comment: Why would you want it? Does it improve readability, or performance? I doubt it.

Comment: Btw, you return the result from within the for each loop, so only the first item in 'test' is handled.

Comment: @Maarten It can improve performance yes. Its related to your foreach/List.Add comment. If the calling code is simply going to add .Any() or .FirstOrDefault() or .Take(), the Enumerator will break early, instead of running through the whole XML doc.

Comment: @Aron, true is doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(...) returns an unevaluated ienumerable (which i do not know since I haven't used Html Agility Pack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (
    from result in 
        from item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='product']")
        from input in item.Descendants("span")
        where input.Attributes["class"].Value == "Bold"
        where input.InnerHtml.ToUpper() == "GetItem"
        select input
    select result
    ).First();
```

Comment: strictly speaking that is correct. But I suspect the .First comes from a bug in the OP's code.

Comment: The premature return would remove the need for a foreach, hence I suspect its a bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd want to gather all the spans together (if I'm correct in assuming that's what you want)...

I'd first convert it to a more fluent notation (I find `SelectMany` much easier to grasp that way - but that's just me)

*(disclaimer: I'm writing this from memory, copy/pasting your code - not by VS at the moment - you'd need to check, make it write if any issues - but I think I got it ok more or less)*

```
var test = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='product']");
foreach(var item in test)
    item.Descendants("span").Where(input => input.Attributes["class"].Value == "Bold").Where(input => input.InnerHtml.ToUpper() == "GetItem").Select(input => input);
```

and finally...

```
var allSpans = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='product']")
    .SelectMany(item => item.Descendants("span").Where(input => input.Attributes["class"].Value == "Bold").Where(input => input.InnerHtml.ToUpper() == "GetItem"));
```

...or along those lines

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to show you the other way to do SelectMany in Linq. This is a style choice, and many people here in SO would prefer the .SelectMany extension method, because they can see how the Monad is applied to the IEnumerable. I prefer this method since its much closer to how a functional programming model would do it.

```
return from product in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='product']")
       from input in product.Descendants("span")
       where input.Attributes["class"].Value == "Bold"
       where input.InnerHtml.ToUpper() == "GetItem"
       select input;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted it all in one query you could with something like this:

```
var result = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='product']")
    .SelectMany(e => e.Descendants("span")
        .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "Bold" && 
                    x.InnerHtml.ToUpper() == "GetItem"))
    .ToList();

return result;
```

I would recommend spacing it out a bit though for the sake of readability, something more like this:

```
var result = new List<SomeType>();
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='product']");

nodes.SelectMany(e => e.Descendants("span")
    .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "Bold" && 
                x.InnerHtml.ToUpper() == "GetItem"));

return result.ToList();
```

The [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method will flatten the results of the inner queries into a single `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Personal opinion: I really do not like the use of ForEach in which you fill a list using someList.Add(...). Please change it to a Select(...) to project it into the wanted type, and eventually use ToList() and store it directly in the result variable.